# Data unable to pass into service once restart the application form device in Android..?

Tags: android, service, android-emulator

Hi friends i have a problem...i want to send string data form activity to service, and i have saved the data into shared preference..mine everything is working, i able to pass data to the service class..but problem is that, if i change the string into shared preference and run my project from eclipse then i am not facing any problem, but i open the application from device or emulator..and then change my string..that time value is not updating in service class, in service class its taking the old data.
I if debug its showing the value, but in device showing old value. Any help please

```
This is the code i tried...
Activity class,From where i sent the value to to the service class using alarm manager

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
// Preference Satting
        prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
}

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

                    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

                    myIntent = new Intent(PZAlarmTTSActivity.this, TtsService.class);

                    passedText = prefs.getString("text", "<unset>");
                    //Log.i("passed Text  :", passedText);

                    // Passing the value to the service
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("k_key", passedText);
                    myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                    Log.i("key Data  :  ", passedText);

                    // Pending intent to launch when the alarm triggers
                    pendintIntent = PendingIntent.getService(PZAlarmTTSActivity.this, 0,
                            myIntent, 0);
                    // Sets alarm to trigger
                    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calender.getTimeInMillis(), pendintIntent);

}


Service class, where i want to receive the string value


@Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Toast.makeText(this, "service started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();  
        String data = bundle.getString("k_key"); // Here data is not updating in 2nd  case
        Log.i("From service class : ", data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see As [Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle) says:

**onStart:This method is deprecated.**

*Implement onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) instead.*

*onStartCommand :Called by the system every time a client explicitly starts the service by calling startService(Intent), providing the arguments it supplied and a unique integer token representing the start request. Do not call this method directly.*

you need to use Threading to get latest value in your service or start your service by using `startService` every time for getting new value from SharedPreferences bez once service is started your `onStart` method is not called if service is already running

this maybe help you!!!

Comment: Hi imran thanks for your help, what ever you told is correct only, but still my application is not working, its taking the old value, if i set new  value its not taking. By the will u send me any simple code to achieve the same.

Comment: simple way friend as i told you if your service is already running then you will not get latest value from   SharedPreferences so you need to make your own logic to watch SharedPreferences  changes in your service and try to call every time to start service by using startService  in onCreate and onResume in your Activity bez at this time i'm not able to provide you any simple code.so try your self.i just point out what is why you are not getting latest value from SharedPreferences.Thanks friend i hope you will understand what i want to explain

Comment: KKC can you try your by putting  onStart code in Timer .plz try it i'm sure you will get latest value.

Comment: Actually if i use startService(intent), its working properly, but i need to call service class in future time..so i used alarmManager.set() method..in that case its not giving proper output. if i re compile and run the proj its working, but when i open it from device giving prob. Any ways let me see, what ever it it will tel

Comment: see my above code if i use startService(myIntent) insted of set.alarmManager(), along with onStartCommand() as u said its working, but i need to use pending intent so that it execute in future. Any idea.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11637/discussion-between-imran-khan-and-kkc)

Comment: solution...pendintIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
           PZAlarmTTSActivity.this, 0, myIntent,
           PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Comment: +1 for getting solution bez i'm busy somewhere that's why i'm not able to make a simple code.thanks friend

Comment: Thanks for your idea, actually from your given idea only i got the solution. Thanks once again.